# How to position the submit button?

Tags: html, css, forms, button, styling

I'm looking to make an offline search page powered by Google. I am having a little trouble with the search button though, it just seems to do whatever it wants. I want it to be relative above the textarea on the left. I would like for it to stay in that corner of the textarea even when the textarea is expanded. (This webpage is not designed for multi-browser supported it is, designed for Firefox only.)

```
    <style>
        body{
            background: url(bg.jpg);
            background-size: cover;}
        textarea{
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 12px;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: poiner;
            border: none;}
        button{
            background-color: #000000;
            border-radius: 12px;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: poiner;
            border: none;}
        button:hover{
            border: none;
            background: #5B93F5;}
        footer{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            text-align: right;
            color: #FFFFFF;}                
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="searchContainer">
        <form id="searchForm" name="searchForm" onsubmit="onSearchSubmit(event)">
                    <button id="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" title="Google Search">
                        <font color="blue">G</font><font color="red">o</font><font color="yellow">o</font><font color="blue">g</font><font color="green">l</font><font color="red">e</font>
                    </button>
            <textarea id="searchText" type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" rows="3" cols="50" autocomplete="off" autofocus></textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
<footer>v5.0</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The button already is above the text area on the right ? http://jsfiddle.net/WLah4/1/

Comment: I would like it attached directly above the box, and to the box.
http://tinypic.com/r/2ch57pj/8

Comment: Please see my answer. The second example may be closer to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following in your css code:

```
#searchContainer { text-align: center; }
#searchContainer > form { display: inline-block; text-align: left; }
```

it should resolve your issue.

Comment: That worked perfectly, I'm not entirely sure how to use the '>' yet. But again thank you very much.

Comment: Pleased its helped you! You can use '>' whenever you need to pick direct child of a parent, like in your case it was 'form' element. To better understand, suppose if there are some 'p' tags inside a div like:

`<div>`
   `<p class="direct-child">....</p>`
       `<p class="not direct-child">.....</p>`
   `<p class="direct-child">....</p>`
   `<p class="direct-child">....</p>`
`</div>`

then to apply your css "only" on 'p' those are directly or at first place inside of div (exclude the 'p' which is inside another 'p') you will use '>' sign, writing `div > p` or `div > .direct-child`.

Answer (score 0):

For the code you have, you can add a padding to the container: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLah4/3/)

Add this line to your CSS:

```
#searchContainer{padding: 2em; display: inline-block;}
```

For a little more style if you want them connected, you can adjust some border-radius' and margins of the button and text area: [JS Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/WLah4/5/)

Comment: I took your formatting idea and made the search button look like a tab at the top, thanks for the idea.